# Use a boolean function to determine the results in Laravel query builder

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have shops that open at a specific time and close at a specific time
and I want to filter these stores according to a time period specified by the user 
so that all the returned shops will be available (opened) at any moment within filtering interval

The shop opens at 10 pm and closes at 2 pm, I mean the shop opens at 10 pm and closes the next day at 2 Pm

I think this is doing the job properly

```
/*
    @param filterStart the beginning of the time period selected by the user in minutes from 00:00.
    @param filterEnd the end of the time period selected by the user in minutes from 00:00.
    @param start the beginning of the period of availability of the shop in minutes from 00:00.
    @param end the end of the period of availability of the shop in minutes from 00:00.
*/
bool ok(int filterStart, int filterEnd , int start, int end) {
    if (filterStart > filterEnd) 
        filterEnd += 24 * 60;

    if (start > end) 
        end += 24 * 60;

    if (start <= filterStart && filterEnd <= end)
        return true;

    if ((start <= (filterStart + 24 * 60)) && ((filterEnd + 24 * 60) <= end))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

I combined the two days on a range (0 to 48 hours) and tested if the shop that open in the first day or open in the second day (the first day + 24 hours)

But I want to use this function to fetch records from database using Laravel.

Can I pass a some function in the WHERE statement in Query Builder to decided it?, Or what is the way to do it?

Comment: What language are you using in your example?

Comment: I'm used C++ in above example.

Comment: Why did you give us a C++ function? You want a communication bewteen a C++ app and PHP server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited my answer after your last comment.

Assuming you can write your C++ function in PHP.

```php
function ok(int $filterStart, int $filterEnd , int $start, int $end): bool {
    if ($filterStart > $filterEnd) 
        $filterEnd += 24 * 60;

    if ($start > $end) 
        $end += 24 * 60;

    if ($start <= $filterStart && $filterEnd <= $end)
        return true;

    if (($start <= ($filterStart + 24 * 60)) && (($filterEnd + 24 * 60) <= $end))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

```php
// User inputs. I wrote 'X' because I don't know enough of your app.
$filterStart = X;
$filterEnd = X;

// Gets all elements of the table 'items'
$items->table('items')
    ->all()

    // Or you can already filters rows with 'where()' in place of 'all()' if you think it is better:
    // ->where('start_time', '>=', $filterStart)
    // ->where('end_time', '<=', $filterEnd)
    // ->get()

    // Do for each elements...
    ->each(function($item, $i) {
        $isOk = ok($filterStart, $filterEnd, $item->start_time, $item->end_time);

        if ($isOk) {
            // Operations to execute if return value is TRUE
        } else {
            // Operations to execute if return value is FALSE
        }
    });
```

I hope it will help you a bit at least!

Comment: But how can me pass the record values to the OK function to make a decision ?

Comment: I want to compare each record in the table with two known values.

Comment: What are your two known values?

Comment: The two known values are: startFilter, endFilter

Comment: I edited my answer. But what you want to do is still not clear in my mind.

Comment: I want exactly:
Perform the function above for each record in a table
Suppose the table has two columns start_time, end_time

I want to execute the following for each record:

If the start_time grater than end_time
Add 24 * 60 to start_time

Then:
I would like to compare start_time and end_time with the previously known values (filter_start, filter_end)

So how I can perform some operations before making a decision.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But is your function only in C++ or is there no problem doing it in PHP?

Comment: Edited my answer supposing you can write your method in PHP.